# Extracting comma seperated values from JSON data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have the following JSON object and I want to use the values to populate a dropdown. I've been trying to get this to work for 2 days and am ready to throw my computer out of the window. Can someone please help me?!

Here's the JSON object...

```
{
"query":"de mar",
"suggestions":[
    "Any Location",
    "Camp De Mar, Majorca, SPAIN",
    "L'amettla De Mar, Costa Dorada, SPAIN",
    "Lloret De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN",
    "Malgrat De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN",
    "Pineda De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN",
    "Roquetas De Mar, Costa De Almeria, SPAIN",
    "Tossa De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN"
],
"data":[
    "",
    "DestinationResort|Camp De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|L'Amettla De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|Lloret De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|Malgrat De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|Pineda De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|Roquetas De Mar",
    "DestinationResort|Tossa De Mar"
]
}
```

And my html and javascript...

```
<input type="text" id="search" data-provide="typeahead">

<select name="destinations" id="destinations"></select>

$("#search").on("input", function() {
$.getJSON( "http://holidays.allinclusive.co.uk/external/destinations.ashx?query=" + $("#search").val() )
.done(function(data) {
$.each(data, function() {
  $.each(this, function(name, value) {
    $( '<option value="' + data.value +'">' + value + '</option>' ).appendTo( "#destinations" );
  })
})
})
});
```

Ultimately I'm looking for something like this...

`<option value="DestinationResort|Camp De Mar">Camp De Mar, Majorca, SPAIN</option>`

Can someone please end my misery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you could reformat the JSON so that the data values and corresponding text are grouped together instead of in two separate arrays, but as long as the arrays are guaranteed to have the same indices you can loop over one and get the corresponding index for the other.

```
$.each(data.suggestions, function (idx, elem) {
    $("select").append(
        $("<option>").val(data.data[idx]).text(elem)
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/BwxtR/

Comment: Dude, I am sending you ALL the love i nthe world right now!!! You ROCK! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Both properties point to arrays and from what I can see your array data is matched by index. So something of the sort should be sufficient:

```
var option = '<option value="' + data.data[index] + '">" + data.suggestions[index] + "</option>";
```

Taking your code:

```
$("#search").on("input", function() {
    $.getJSON( "http://holidays.allinclusive.co.uk/external/destinations.ashx?query=" + $("#search").val() )
        .done(function(data) {
            for (var index = 0; index < data.data.length; index++) {
                var option = '<option value="' + data.data[index] + '">" + data.suggestions[index] + "</option>";
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var json={"query":"de mar","suggestions":[    "Any Location",    "Camp De Mar, Majorca, SPAIN",    "L'amettla De Mar, Costa Dorada, SPAIN",    "Lloret De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN",    "Malgrat De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN",    "Pineda De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN",    "Roquetas De Mar, Costa De Almeria, SPAIN",    "Tossa De Mar, Costa Brava, SPAIN"],"data":[    "",    "DestinationResort|Camp De Mar",    "DestinationResort|L'Amettla De Mar",    "DestinationResort|Lloret De Mar",    "DestinationResort|Malgrat De Mar",    "DestinationResort|Pineda De Mar",    "DestinationResort|Roquetas De Mar",   "DestinationResort|Tossa De Mar"]};


$.each(json.suggestions, function(index,value) {
    $( '<option value="'+json.data[index]+'">'+value+'</option>').appendTo("#destinations" );
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/DbVUa/